# python dynamically create attributes class

Tags: python

I am facing issues adding class attributes dynamically from a list of strings, consider the following scenario:

This is my class:

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        self.__dict__ = kw

    def add_attributes(self,**kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)  

#a group of attributes i want to associate with the class
list = []
list.append("name")
list.append("age")
list.append("gender")

Customer c

for i in list:
    # i is the attribute name for the class
    c.add_attributes( i = "test")
```

The issue seems to be the fact that it is treating the attribute name as a string, can someone please advise

Comment: c = Customer(), thats the error ?

Comment: You have to correct indentation..

Comment: OT: do not use 'list' as a variable, otherwise this will override standard 'list' function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i = "test"` is actually converted to `{'i':'test'}` when passed to `**kwargs` inside `add_attributes`, so you need to do something like this:

```
for i in my_list:
    c.add_attributes(**{ i : "test"})
```

Comment: This produces dictionaries with `i` as the key, and `'test'` as the value, then uses the `**kw` syntax to apply the dictionary as keyword arguments to the `c.add_attributes()` method.

Comment: @godzilla Read about keyword arguments: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: thanks Ashwini, i will do, one last question, if i wanted to iterate over the attributes and print them along with their corresponding values, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @godzilla `self.__dict__.items()` will return key, value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly updating __dict__, you can use the [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) builtin method:

```
for i in list:
    # i is the attribute name for the class
    setattr(c, i, "test")
```

In my opinion, playing with internal attributes should be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a for-loop, you could use [dict.fromkeys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
c.add_attributes(**dict.fromkeys(seq, "test"))
```

since

```
In [13]: dict.fromkeys(seq, "test")
Out[13]: {'age': 'test', 'gender': 'test', 'name': 'test'}
```

The `**` tells Python to unpack the dict into keyword arguments.
The syntax is explained [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) and in the [docs, here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

---

By the way, it's best not to use `list` as a variable name, since it makes it difficult to access the builtin of the same name.